# How can I move the whole layout to adapt to pre-printed form on different printers

Tags: java, jasper-reports

We have US Healthcare Medical Billing Product developed using Java, Hibernate, Spring and Jasper Report 5.6. that are printing with CMS 1500 and UB04 Form.

We want to print the values in the **pre printed form** i.e user will keep the this pre printed form in the printer and from the application we need to print the values in the boxes.

So we attached the image in the Jasper Report and put the text boxes in each of the boxes. It is printing correctly, but if the user **change the printer**, then **alignment** is becomes a **problem**. As a alternate dirty option, we took the copy and make the alignment for that printer, so now for every printer we have separate jasper report file even though the values that are printed are the same.

My client is asking to give them a option to **set the X and Y value** in separate form and then use these values to print correctly.

So the question is can we do this in jasper reports?

[image: Pre printed form]

Comment: To Understand Better http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/538265/preprinted-form-how-fix-textfield-absolute-position-xy

Comment: Do I understand the question correctly if I state that you are looking for away to move all JRElements with X and Y values provided by user?..... Are you looking for a solution in java or in jrxml?, futhermore can the X and Y values be negative or only positive?

Comment: Yes Your understanding is correct. I am looking solution in java. X and Y can be either negative or positive

Comment: I edit your post, reflecting your needs so it maybe more useful to others.

Comment: Yes i was in hurry to find out solution. Now every thing is fine. Your solution works perfectly for me.

Comment: Hello @SenthilMuthiah, Are you able to achieve this task?. If yes, then could you please guide me to this. I have also an urgent requirement for this.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xGn2yKsPPsI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to **move all** report elements is to modify the report **margins**

Load the `jrxml` in to the `JasperDesign` object and switch margins as desired. The minimum you can move in x is the original report margin, the maximum depends on your report (naturally the columWidth can not become 0, but has no really sense checking this better to define a max)

**Example:**

```
JasperDesign design = JRXmlLoader.load("YourReport.jrxml");
moveDesign(design,x,y);
JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(design);

private void moveDesign(JasperDesign design, int x, int y) {
    int maxX = 100; //I define it so that elements is not out of report
    int maxY = 100;

    int pageWidth = design.getPageWidth();
    int intitalLeftMargin = design.getLeftMargin();
    int intitalRightMargin = design.getRightMargin();
    int intitalTopMargin= design.getTopMargin();

    //Check that not less then 0 and not more then my max       
    int newLeftMargin = Math.min(Math.max(intitalLeftMargin+x,0),maxX);
    int newTopMargin = Math.min(Math.max(intitalTopMargin+y,0),maxY);

    //set our new margins
    int newColumWidth = pageWidth - newLeftMargin - intitalRightMargin;
    design.setLeftMargin(newLeftMargin);
    design.setTopMargin(newTopMargin);
    design.setColumnWidth(newColumWidth);
}
```

The down-side of this is that you need to **recompile** your report (this will take a couple of ms).

If execution speed is of fundamental importance another solution (more complex but probably faster) is to move all elements in every page in the `JasperPrint`

I will leave the complete code to OP but it will be similar to this

```
List<JRPrintPage> pages = jasperPrint.getPages();
for (JRPrintPage jrPrintPage : pages) {
    List<JRPrintElement> elements = jrPrintPage.getElements();
    for (JRPrintElement jjpe : elements) {
        jjpe.setX(newX);
        jjpe.setY(newX);    
    }   
}
```

Comment: In the fastest method, we dont need to recompile ?

Comment: JasperDesign design = null;
design = JRXmlLoader.load(reportPath);
JRElement jasperelement = null;
jasperelement = design.getPageHeader().getElementByKey('keyname');
if (jasperelement != null) 
{
 jasperelement.setX(tmp.getXpos());
 
}
Here i am not set jasperelement.setY because there is no method in JRElement . How we can set veritical position ?

Comment: Fastest method, no you do not need to recompile, the jrxml to .jasper, but in your case the user printing will hardly see any difference (0.1-0.2 sec), mostly I have added the faster method if some one needs to execute this is batch (generating 1000 of reports)

Comment: You need to cast it to is correct class (is it a textElement or image??), if you don't know which use JRBaseElement  ((JRBaseElement)tmp).setY(...)...

Comment: Yes Got it.  Petter Small Correction. From your example, we need to save JRML File and then compile as follows    JasperCompileManager.writeReportToXmlFile(design, reportPath);
   JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(design, outputFile);

Comment: Hmm, is the above comment a question or just a statement?, you may do whatever you like....

Comment: If it is a question, do we need to save the JasperDesign before we compile?, the answer is NO. The code in answer is actually working code.