# How to set margins to jasper report in java?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

How to set margins to jasper report in java!

I have reports.jasper with margins,but when print I must change margins!

`JasperPrint.setTopMargins(myMarginsValue)` doesn't work!!!

I use `JRPrintServiceExporter` to send to the printer!

**Current code:**

```
InputStream reportStream = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream("/rep‌​orts/" + "myReport"+".jasper"); 
JasperReport template = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(reportStream);
template.setWhenNoDataType(WhenNoDataTypeEnum.ALL_SECTIONS_NO_DETAIL);
```

Comment: Please add some code to show your progress and help us understand your problem better.

Comment: InputStream reportStream = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream("/reports/" + "myReport"+".jasper");
        
        JasperReport template = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(reportStream);
        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(template, parametarTest, connection);                                  PrintRequestAttributeSet printRequestAttributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        printRequestAttributeSet.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);

Comment: You should [edit] your post do not pass additional info as comment, I have passed an answer, note you will load the jrxml file not the jasper file.

Comment: PrintServiceAttributeSet printServiceAttributeSet = new HashPrintServiceAttributeSet();
        
        JRPrintServiceExporter exporter = new JRPrintServiceExporter();
        PrintService defaultPrinter = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
        
            exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(print));

            SimplePrintServiceExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePrintServiceExporterConfiguration();
             configuration.setPrintRequestAttributeSet(printRequestAttributeSet);@PetterFriberg

Comment: configuration.setPrintService(defaultPrinter);
            configuration.setDisplayPageDialog(false);
            configuration.setDisplayPrintDialog(false);
            exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
            exporter.exportReport(); @legrandviking

Comment: Its ok, no need for all this code... The margins are set as in answer...

Comment: If you still have problem just ping me...

Comment: When I use JasperCompileManager :Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException: Report design not valid : 
  1. The columns and the margins do not fit the page width.
  2. The title section, the page and column headers and footers and the margins do not fit the page height.
  3. The page and column headers and footers and the margins do not fit the page height.
  4. The page and column headers and footers and the margins do not fit the last page height. My printer is Dot Matrix! @PetterFriberg

Comment: @Landre, if you change the margins the 1. columnWidht need to be changed as well (see answer), 2, 3,4 You need to change the height of correct band... at a certain point it will not fit anymore, hence also textFields may go out from layout. If your purpose is translating the layout see the link I have edited in to answer.

Comment: I'm kind of wondering if maybe you are not searching for how to set margins in jasper report (as in question), but the PrintableArea to the printer (hence only when you print, not when you export)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the **jrxml** (note not the .jasper) into the [JasperDesign](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/design/JasperDesign.html) using the [JRXmlLoader](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/xml/JRXmlLoader.html)

```
JasperDesign design = JRXmlLoader.load(stream); //Location of jrxml file example FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream("/rep‌​orts/" + "myReport"+".jrxml");
design.setBottomMargin(bottomMargin); //set the margins
design.setTopMargin(topMargin)
design.setLeftMargin(leftMargin)
design.setRightMargin(rightMargin);
design.setColumnWidth(design.getPageWidth()-leftMargin-rightMargin);//if you change your left and right margin you need to set new correct columnWidth

//compile the report
JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(design); //this is what you called template
```

Then **fill** it and **export** it as you wish.

Naturally textField may be out side of design, band may not fit the page height if you increase your margins to much, this needs to be attended to as appropriate.

This is another similar question with full code if the purpose is moving layout to adapt to pre-printed form: [How can I move the whole layout to adapt to pre-printed form on different printers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34696385/how-can-i-move-the-whole-layout-to-adapt-to-pre-printed-form-on-different-printe/34706222#34706222)

Comment: Thanky you very much! @PetterFreiberg